# amcharts4 Format date from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a simple area chart and I would like to show the right date with hours and minutes. I have a const for converting unix timestamp :

```
const formatDate = inputDate => {
    const date1 = new Date(inputDate * 1000);

    let day = date1.getDate();
    let month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date1.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    }
    const formattedDate = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Here is my full code :

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.dataSource.url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/8se3o";

const formatDate = inputDate => {
    const date1 = new Date(inputDate * 1000);

    let day = date1.getDate();
    let month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date1.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    }
    const formattedDate = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    return formattedDate;
}

chart.data = chart.data.map(element => {
  element.time = formatDate(element.time)
  return element;
});




var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series.name = "outDiff";
series.dataFields.valueY = "outDiff";
series.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.stacked = true;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.name = "inDiff";
series2.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "inDiff";
series2.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series2.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series2.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series2.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series2.stacked = true;
series2.strokeWidth = 2;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();


chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "top";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

All data from time key are from todays date (19/04/2019)

Comment: You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for time related stuff. Is there an error? or it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong with your code.

First, amCharts expects dates to be sorted in [ascending order](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Order_of_data_items). Your data is currently out of order, causing the chart to look weird.

Second, you don't need to format your data in string format. You can still use your timestamp (provided that you multiply by 1000 seconds) and use the chart's `dateFormatter` to parse it through the `"x"` code in `inputDateFormatter`, as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/#Parsing_dates).

Since you're using `dataSource`, you can use the `parseended` event to [manipulate your data before it is assigned to the chart](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/#Manipulating_loaded_data) like so:

```
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
  // parsed data is assigned to data source's `data` property
  var data = ev.target.data;
  data.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs.time - rhs.time;
  });
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.time *= 1000;
  });
});

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "x";
```

To change the dates, you have to modify your date axis' `dateFormats` and `periodChangeDateFormats` list objects and set the appropriate date format for the period(s) you want to reformat. Since your data is in minutes, you'll want to call `setKey` on the `minutes` period and adjust accordingly as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Setting_date_formats), for example:

```
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("minute", "MMM dd\nHH:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("minute", "MMM dd\nHH:mm");
```

Fully updated code below:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.dataSource.url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/8se3o";
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
  // parsed data is assigned to data source's `data` property
  var data = ev.target.data;
  data.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs.time - rhs.time;
  });
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    item.time *= 1000;
  });
});

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "x";


var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("minute", "MMM dd\nHH:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("minute", "MMM dd\nHH:mm");

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series.name = "outDiff";
series.dataFields.valueY = "outDiff";
series.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.stacked = true;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.name = "inDiff";
series2.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "inDiff";
series2.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}</b></span>";
series2.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series2.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series2.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series2.stacked = true;
series2.strokeWidth = 2;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();


chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "top";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know what cause the issu but if you hover on a point you will see, the lowest value is rendered higher on the chart. For example the first point 568964 is drawned highter than 574646

Comment: That's because you're stacking the graphs, which adds the line on top of the other one. This is how stacking graphs works. If you don't want this, set `stacked` to false.